# how to share captured photo to using Adding an Easy Share Action in android?

Tags: android

Am doing photo sharing in my application.for that am using Adding an Easy Share Action.it show only icon in the action bar,not options.so please suggest me with some example.

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can address the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy Share is auto-populating; you only need to tell the **ShareActionProvider** what content it is you will be sharing.

Most of this is shared in the API link you provided, but if you are aiming to populate the list for the images you aim to be sharing, you would need to include this.

```
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.setType("image/*");
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg"));
  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri.toString());
```

Now that the **shareIntent** has been set to image, it will populate the list with the related apps, such as instagram, facebook or PhotoShop.

The app will view the images as a **MIME** type ([Multipurpose Internet Mail Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)) in one of the types found here when you call *shareIntent.setType*.